# FFMPEG undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_146'

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, x264

When configuring FFMPEG with below modules show error,

```
# ./configure  --enable-shared --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --extra-libs=-lx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslin --enable-libass --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-libx264
```

> CC    ffmpeg_filter.o LD  ffmpeg_g libavcodec/libavcodec.so: undefined
>   reference to `x264_encoder_open_146' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   **status make:** ****  **[ffmpeg_g] Error 1**

I found the lib files,

```
#  ls  /usr/local/lib | grep libx264
libx264.a
libx264.so@
libx264.so.144*
libx264.so.146*
```

How to fixed it.?

Comment: Which file does the `libx264.so` link point at?

Comment: libx264.so.146*  - I have installed multiple times but still getting errors. If i have removed the module : --enable-libx264 it's working fine. But i must need this : libx264

Comment: You have `--enable-shared` in there twice. You also have `--extra-ldflags` twice (with different values) but I'd be worried about those not being combined. Why do you use **both** `--enable-libx264` and `--extra-libs=-lx264` do you need both? I wouldn't expect you do.

Comment: I hope there is no issue if i have added : --extra-ldflags twise. Also i remove --extra-libs=-lx264 this one, getting same error.

Comment: Can you try with a single `--extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib -L/usr/local/lib"` and see if that helps? What does the command that throws that error look like?

Comment: i have remove the libx264.* file from the path and reinstalled again with latest version. its solved. shall i given the steps on answers box ?

Comment: If there's something you can point at specifically as the cause and/or solution that seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution,

May be package installed version conflict ,

Find the installed packages and remove it,

```
#  rpm -qa | grep x264

x264-0.0.0-0.4.20101111.el6.rf.x86_64
```

remove libx264 by rpm,

```
#  rpm -e x264-0.0.0-0.4.20101111.el6.rf.x86_64
```

make ensure the below packages are installed in your system, If its not available install

```
# yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel ffmpeg-libpostproc
```

Then, install x264 devel and x264 package,

```
#  yum install x264-devel x264
```

Now, download the x264 package  by git and install,

```
# cd /usr/local/src

# git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git

# cd  x264

# ./configure --enable-shared  --enable-asm

# make && make install
```

Now, you can try to configure the FFMPEG again.

Comment: Why would you `--disable-asm`?

Comment: there is no issue if you have enabled it.